# Rally SDK collection store sync throwing 404

Tags: javascript, post, sdk, rally

EDIT: I ended up using Rally.data.util.Record.serverSideCopy() and re-retrieving/updating the new testcase to finish this work up. I'm leaving this unresolved as I still can't figure out why I was getting the 404 on sync (though, I'll likely not have time to dig into it since I went in a different direction).

I'm attempting to add TestCaseSteps to a TestCase (which I copied from another TestCase - original collection of steps was lost during the save as they were associated with the original TestCase).  I tried following the add/sync pattern suggested in the [Collection Modification section of the doc](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/guide/collections_in_v2) , but supplying only the _ref value of the Steps caused the sync() operation to fail with a 404 on the POST:

```
HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /slm/webservice/v2.0/TestCase/90167266916/Steps/add. Reason:

Not Found
```

As seen below, I then attempted to add the Steps via raw objects instead of _ref values, but I received the same 404.

What am I doing wrong here?  Why are my sync operations resulting in a 404?

For further context, here's the repo:
https://github.com/crdschurch/reuse-rally-test

```
var newSteps = newTestCase.getCollection('Steps', {autoLoad: true});

  oldTestCase.getCollection('Steps').load({
    callback: function(oldRecords, newOperation, newSuccess) {
      Ext.Array.each(oldRecords, function(step) {
        console.log(step.get('_ref'));
        //debugger;
        newSteps.add(
          {
            'Input': step.get('Input'),
            'ExpectedResult': step.get('ExpectedResult'),
            'StepIndex': step.get('StepIndex'),
            'TestCase': newTestCase.get('ObjectID')
          }
        );
      });

      console.log('Syncing: ');
      console.log(newSteps);

      newSteps.sync({
        callback: function() {
          console.log('New Test: ');
          console.log(newTestCase);
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need to specify TestCase as a ref rather than just its objectid:

```
newSteps.add({
    'Input': step.get('Input'),
    'ExpectedResult': step.get('ExpectedResult'),
    'StepIndex': step.get('StepIndex'),
    'TestCase': newTestCase.get('_ref')
});
```

Comment: I ended up solving this in a different manner, but I did go back and try out what you suggested, using the test case ref when adding the steps. I still received a 404 on the sync call and the added steps were not in the new test.

To solve the issue, I went back to the doc and found Rally.data.util.Record.serverSideCopy().  This added a call to my flow (the original test case is copied in Rally, then I have to retrieve it and make updates/save again), but it grabs the Test Case Steps collection on the server side copy.

Code is here: https://github.com/crdschurch/reuse-rally-test